# Distribution of throughput among different thread groups in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Below is the actual volume i need to achieve in 1 hour of my jmeter load test.

Required Request/second=0.14 (520/3600)

[image: Volume chart]

Hence i have Throughput shaping timer with Start RPS and End RPS as 0.14 for 3600 Sec.

i have 2 thread groups.
Thread group 1 has transactions- Launch and Login.

**TG1**

```
                **Thread Group** 
                    Launch
                    Login
```

Thread group 2 has Action1 and Action2 transactions.

**TG2**

```
               **Thread group**
                 **Action1** 
                 **Action2**
```

Having all these under one thread group ,i can achieve anticipated load using combination of No Of **threads** required and **Throughput COntroller**.

But here my requirement is ,i have transactions in different thread groups.

Can anyone tell my how can i distribute the throughput for two different Thread groups.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to apply the same approach as for the single Thread Group to any amount of Thread Groups.

Throughput Controller obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules) so if you place it to be as a child of the 2nd Thread Group - it will not have any impact on other Thread Groups

Also be aware that in some cases it's easier to use [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) for requests distribution, check out [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I'm declaring the throughput shaping timer globally ,so that both the TGs have access. How can i distribute total users among 2 thread groups ,(formula Total users=TPS*(Resp time in Sec)).Will distibuting enough users appropriately serve the purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting for specific number of requests per second the best approach is to use

[bzm - Arrivals Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ArrivalsThreadGroup/)

It automatically adjusts userload and maintains target RPS levels.

You are targeting 0.14 request per second that means 8.4 requests per minute so in arrivals thread group enter 8 arrivals per minute (It accepts only whole numbers so you can round off to 8 or 9)
Enter Rampup rate steps and maximum number of concurrent users (This helps to limit max number of users )

[image]

And inside the thread group you can use throughput controllers to control your transaction executions as shown in above screenshot.

Please refer to the sample test plan from the [link](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/74544) ( you can find it in details section of the report).

Comment: And i have got one more doubt,,how the load be distributed ,if ACTION1 has one more request Act2 which should take 50% of the ACTION1 load.considering Action1 is a group of 2 transactions.